# Javascript datepicker onSelect doesnt fire

Tags: javascript, forms, input, datepicker

I want to print " 18:00-19:00" in the input field if day 1 or 3 is clicked, else " 11:00-12.00" which would be day 6.

All of the below code works as expected, besides the onselect function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    function DisableDays(date) {
         var day = date.getDay();
         if (day == 2 || day == 4 || day == 5 || day == 0) {
             return [false] ; 
         } else {
             return [true]
         } 
     }

    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
           beforeShowDay: DisableDays, 
           minDate: "+1", maxDate: "+14", 
           onSelect: function(datetext, date) {         
                         var day = date.getDay();
                         if (day == 1 || day == 3) {
                             datetext = datetext + " 11:00-12:00";
                             jQuery('#datepicker').val(datetext);
                         } else {
                             datetext = datetext + " 18:00-19:00";
                             jQuery('#datepicker').val(datetext);
                         }
                     } 
         });
    });
});
```

When i click a day in the calendar, i get thrown to the top of the page, but it does put the date in the input field, just not the " 18:00-19:00" or " 11:00-12:00"

Comment: Why do people use jQuery instead of $? Saw it before, but I don't get it. (Sorry not relevant to your question right now). Why isn't everything in the same document ready function? On topic: datepicker has also an event changeDate. Maybe try that one? After data changed, get the date and add text to it.

Comment: There is some conflict with Wordpress when using $

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post my solution:

```
function DisableDays(date) {
     var day = date.getDay();
     if (day == 2 || day == 4 || day == 5 || day == 0) {
         return [false];
     } else {
         return [true];
     } 
 }

jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
       beforeShowDay: DisableDays, 
       minDate: "+1", maxDate: "+14", 
       onSelect: function (datetext) { 
                    var dateMin = jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate");
                    var d = new Date(dateMin);
                    var n = d.getDay();
                     if (n == 1 || n == 3) {
                         datetext = datetext + " 18:00-19:00";
                         jQuery('#datepicker').val(datetext);
                     } else {
                         datetext = datetext + " 11:00-12:00";
                         jQuery('#datepicker').val(datetext);
                     }
                 } 
     });
});
```